# Changing values of selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I want to create an online spinner calculator. So far I stored the number values for calculation inside a selecbox, but now I have a problem updating the values. In example below if I choose **Linux** the pricing options should be **5,10,20**. If **Windows** is choosen, then **50,70,100**.

```js
$(".prev").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('select').find('option:selected').prev().prop('selected', true);
});

$(".next").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('select').find('option:selected').next().prop('selected', true);
});
```

```css
.prev, .next {
    width: 13px;
    height: 18px;
    padding: 2px 0 0 7px;
    background-color: #6c6c6c;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calc">
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"><</div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected value="0">Linux</option>
                <option value="1">Windows</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next">></div>
        </div>
        <div class="selector">
            <div class="prev"><</div>
            <select class="val">
                <option selected value="5">5</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
            </select>
            <div class="next">></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all of the possible values into the  tag

Then when the user selects "Windows", have it hide the options for 5,10, and 20- and show the other values

Then if they select "Linux", have it do the opposite

Make sense? I can write the code out for you if needed...